# Watermark large areas in a video based on color masking

Tags: video, digital-watermarking

Consider this watermarked image:

[image: windows xp wallpaper with "watermark"]

I've done this in Photoshop by superimposing the watermark (diagonal repeated text) onto the blue sky area of the image (with the help of Magic Wand tool).

What software could help me do this in a video easily? I.e. apply the watermark similarly onto "blue sky" or any other large areas of the video based on color masking.

Optionally, it'd be nice if it could process large number of videos in batch.

- Windows, any license, free or paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [python](https://www.python.org/) [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) tool, *(which installs and uses FFMPEG and needs [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed for text operations),* can be used to create a colour mask clip based on a specified colour, *using [mask_color](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.mask_color.html)* and you can then use it to apply a watermark similar to the masked credits [example](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/examples/masked_credits.html), *(https://youtu.be/NsTgBah6Ebk for the results)*, but with more transparency.

Providing that the colour that you wished to watermark are close to each other there is no reason that you couldn't batch process numerous videos or you could supply the target colour as a parameter, (possibly with *filename.ext[R,G,B]* used for the input parameter of the script then parsing the parameter).

All of the above tools are Free, Gratis & Open Source and are available for Windows, Linux & Mac.

*Before anybody moans about the spelling of colour I am English and that is the correct spelling where I am.*